# Why are my working proxies not working in Python requests?

Tags: python, networking, proxy, python-requests

I have been testing proxies with me and 5 other people. 2/5 people get the same result as me, and the other 3/5 people get a valid response. We are all using the same proxy and same exact code. I have tried thousands upon thousands of other proxies and all of them give me the same error.

It does not seem to be a failure between me and the proxy, as I have tried using these proxies in proxy testers and they return valid responses.

#### Expected Result

For the request to give a valid response / not fail

#### Actual Result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
self._prepare_proxy(conn)
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
conn.connect()
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 371, in connect
self._tunnel()
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _tunnel
(version, code, message) = response._read_status()
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Allen/Desktop/AnalogAIO CLI/ProxyTest.py", line 15, in
res = session.get("https://httpbin.org/")
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 510, in send
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

#### Reproduction Steps

```py
import requests

session = requests.Session()
proxy = "ip:port:user:pass"  # Put an actual proxy here

# split proxy into host and port and user and password
host, port, user, password = proxy.split(":")

proxies = {
    "http": "http://{}:{}@{}:{}".format(user, password, host, port),
    "https": "http://{}:{}@{}:{}".format(user, password, host, port)
}

session.proxies.update(proxies)
res = session.get("https://httpbin.org/")
print(res.status_code)
```

#### System Information

```json
{
  "chardet": {
    "version": "3.0.4"
  },
  "charset_normalizer": {
    "version": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cryptography": {
    "version": ""
  },
  "idna": {
    "version": "3.3"
  },
  "implementation": {
    "name": "CPython",
    "version": "3.7.9"
  },
  "platform": {
    "release": "10",
    "system": "Windows"
  },
  "pyOpenSSL": {
    "openssl_version": "",
    "version": null
  },
  "requests": {
    "version": "2.26.0"
  },
  "system_ssl": {
    "version": "1010107f"
  },
  "urllib3": {
    "version": "1.26.7"
  },
  "using_charset_normalizer": false,
  "using_pyopenssl": false
}
```

Comment: looks like the remote server is not responding ( Max retries exceeded ) maybe is saturated, try at different times, or try a different proxy

Comment: or try downgrading urllib to ( urllib3==1.25.8 ) and then remove the 'http://', and 'https://' and try again. Somebody said latest urllib3 has a bug, don't take it from me though...